# Looking for an accurate way to micro benchmark small code paths written in C++ and running on Linux/OSX

Tags: c++, linux, performance, benchmarking

I'm looking to do some very basic micro benchmarking of small code paths, such as tight loops, that I've written in C++. I'm running on Linux and OSX, and using GCC. What facilities are there for sub millisecond accuracy? I am thinking a simple test of running the code path many times (several tens of millions?) will give me enough consistency to get a good reading. If anyone knows of preferable methods, please feel free to suggest them.

Comment: Kludgy solution, but you can use `python -m timeit -n NUMBEROFTIMES 'import subprocess; subprocess.call("./yourexecutable")'`

Comment: I guess you're on Intel/AMD?  You could read the CPU clock register (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) with RDTSC (if you run on a single core or your BIOS et al happen to properly sync across cores, and you're not using some variable clock speed).

Comment: The Shark is a great tool in the MacOSx http://developer.apple.com/tools/sharkoptimize.html

Comment: @Rafe - that's a good way to benchmark all of the bootstrapping that happens before `main()`.  The noise from that will outweigh any truly small code path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `"rdtsc"` processor instruction on x86/x86_64. For multicore systems check the "constant_tsc" capability in CPUID (/proc/cpuinfo in linux) - it will mean that all cores use the same tick counter, even with dynamic freq changing and sleeping.

If your processor does not support constant_tsc, be sure to bind you programm to the core (`taskset` utility in Linux).

When using rdtsc on out-of-order CPUs (All besides Intel Atom, may be some other low-end cpus), add an "ordering" instruction before, e.g. "cpuid" - it will temporary disable instruction reordering.

Also, MacOsX has "Shark" which can measure some hardware events in your code.

`RDTSC` and out-of-order CPUs. More info in section 18 of the 2nd great Fog's manual on optimization: [*Optimizing subroutines in assembly language: An optimization guide for x86 platforms*](https://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf) (the main site with all the five manuals is http://www.agner.org/optimize/)

http://www.scribd.com/doc/1548519/optimizing-assembly

> On all processors with out-of-order execution, you have to insert XOR EAX,EAX / CPUID
>   before and after each read of the counter in order to prevent it from executing in parallel
>   with anything else. CPUID is a serializing instruction, which means that it flushes the
>   pipeline and waits for all pending operations to finish before proceeding. This is very useful
>   for testing purposes.

Comment: I've been under the impression that `__asm__ __volatile__` prevents reordering.  Is that not sufficient?

Comment: Thanks osgx, can you explain a bit more why the reordering should be disabled? If reordering is done, isn't it constant for the entire run? Or is there the potential for the reordering to be non-deterministic?

Comment: Complex Fish, RDTSC will be reordered if it will be used without any ordering instruction. To get exact tick count, you must to insert a syncronization point near the rdtsc. This is recommendation from Intel manuals, also from here ... will put it in the answer

Comment: Tom, yes. `__asm__ __volatile__("")` (also called "Compiler memory barrier"  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering#Compiler_memory_barrier ) prevents compiler from reordering and not emitted as some code. But modern CPU's reorders in hardware execution of instructions read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution

Comment: @osgx  Not true, GCC will freely move asm code, even if it's marked as asm volatile.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've used in the past:

```
inline double gettime ()
{
    timeval tv;
    gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
    return double (tv.tv_sec) + 0.000001 * tv.tv_usec;
}
```

And then:

```
double startTime = gettime();
// your code here
double runTime = gettime() - startTime;
```

This will quote to the microsecond.

Comment: This will be a seconds with microsecond resolution.

Comment: Run `gettimeofday()` in a tight loop, and compare all of the deltas between them.  You'll find that some of the deltas are quite large for a "micro benchmark".

Answer (score 0):

[Cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html) / [kCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) are good for very fine-grained profiling.  I don't believe they're available for OS X, but the results you get on Linux should be representative.

Comment: does cachegrid profile the real code on real processor or simulate real code on some virtual model of processor?

Comment: @osgx: Neither - it runs the code on the real processor, but counts each memory access against a simulated cache structure.  Each time an instruction is executed, an I-cache read is accounted to the corresponding line of source, meaning you can count instructions (and if you examine the assembler, together with cachegrind's cache miss statistics, you can convert instruction counts into cycle counts for a particular processor model - however raw instruction counts are usually fine).

Comment: caf, it is valgrind based, yes? So it will use libvex(?) to dynamically instrument the code. It can be rather accurate in terms of cache/memory access count; it will simulate cache behaviour; but it can't say anything on real execution time of some code (the code is changed by cachegrind; the cache is polluted by instrumentation counters). Is it? The branch misprediction and cache misses are not the only limiting factors for performance of programms.

Comment: the author wants to measure time, nor the cache access count neither branch count. Cachegrind will change time.

Comment: The cache logic provided by cachegrind has two significant limitations: It doesn't simulate N layers of caching (new Intel chips have unified L3 caches as well as L2 caches), and it doesn't handle cache-related interactions with other processes.  That may lead to mild disappointment when running on modern hardware.

Comment: @osgx: As I said, given a particular architecture you can convert the execution count, cache misses and branch mispredictions into a cycle cost for each line, which is a measure of CPU time.  It is my experience that fine-grained profiling is typically done on CPU-bound problems, and thus CPU time is likely to be useful.  IO-bound problems are better attacked by analysing the IO patterns directly.

Comment: caf, if I have memory access count and branching statistics, I can get only execution count for basic blocks (how many times was this instruction executed on cpu). But I cant get exact time for computation-intensive code, like large fp/sse computation which does not use memory a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Microbenchmark should run the same code in a loop, preferably over lots of iteration.
I used the following and ran it with time(1) utility;

following caveats were observed

- if the test does not produce a computation that is printed out then code is eliminated by optimization - gcc with -O3 does that.
- the test functions of test() and lookup() must be implemented in a different source file than the loop of the iteration; if they are in the same file and the lookup function returns constant value then code optimization would not call it, not once once, it would just multiply the return value by number of iterations !

file main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define RUN_COUNT 10000000

void init();
int  lookup();


main()
{
  int sum = 0;
  int i;

  init();


  for(i = 0; i < RUN_COUNT; i++ ) {
    sum  += lookup();
  }

  printf("%d", sum );
}
```